# datetime(6) works on XAMPP but not on latest Ubuntu MySQL server

Tags: mysql, datetime, ubuntu

I have an API i can only use 1000 times everyday.

So everytime i call the api i place a timestamp in a database.
Now if i place a timestamp in a database in the same second, and it is primary key, i get an exception so the problem was solved by adding (6) (number of fraction of a second)

```
CREATE TABLE `apicall` (
  `timestamp` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

If i use workbench and place this in my MySQL from Xampp on windows, this runs fine and without problems.

If i add the exact same code in workbench on my ubuntu LAMP server, it says there is a syntax error.

Does anyone know why, have documentation why, link to a blog why? Or maybe more important, have a suggesiton to a posible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a version difference of mysql between the local and the ubuntu server.

In your local you have at-least MySQL 5.6.4 where in Ubuntu its less than that, and prior that version the `datetime(n)` was  not supported.

Check here for more details

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html

In this case you may need to use as

```
CREATE TABLE `apicall` (
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Note that in older version of Mysql you can not have

```
`timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This needs to be

```
`timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

However from MySQL 5.6.5 you can have it.

Comment: This is properly for serverfault, but do you happen to know how to get that version of MySQL for ubuntu, this one was a clean install from yesterday. If not it is ok, i can just do a fast google.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html Found it ... thanks

Comment: check in ubuntu after login to mysql and run this command `select version();` this will show you the version. If its an old one you may do update or install the latest version.